# Error message:Project Android.Common is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

In my project for Xamarin I have a strange error message:
Project Android.Common is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project Android.Common supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1) 
I use Visual Studio 15.9.5 and Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1009999 in the project
I don't have any idea how I can resolve.

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you try to add any package? Is your project in NETSTANDARD2.0 already?

Comment: I have the setting compile using android version "Android 8.1 (Oreo)". I have included in this project also NetStandardLibrary 2.0.3 with nuget

Comment: Your .Net standard library should not have any naitve android or ios libraries keep an eye for that

Comment: First I don't had any dependency to .net Standard 2.0. I have tested this only and it doesn't help....

Comment: I have found the problem. In an project (not android, there was a dependency to an android project...)

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. In an project (not android, there was a dependency to an android project